# Is point $a$ a Inflection point?

Tags: calculus

> An inflection point is a point on a curve at which the sign of the curvature  changes

Now Suppose function $f$ As follows :

[image]

Is point $a$  a Inflection point?

Comment: I refuse to believe that the question is well-defined, because the definition is not rigorous.

Comment: I know about *inflection points* as points in which the curvature vanishes. But $f$ does not even have a curvature in $a$ because it is not differentiable there. So I would say No. But your "definition" leaves room to argue (which means you should think about the meaningfulness of your definition).

Answer (score 2):

The [usual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point#Definition)  of inflexion point is different from your definition and require the existence of a tangent line at this point. So your point $(a,f(a))$ is not an inflection point.

Comment: look http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InflectionPoint.html

Comment: I don't like this definition because it  seems require, implicitly, that a curvature at the point exists, so that the function is differentable.